Physical observables are independent of renormalization point - Is this true?
In the page 350 of QFT book of Schwartz, it says:

The subtraction point μ allows for a one-parameter family of renormalization conditions. Physical predictions that relate observables to other observables must be independent of μ.

so it sounds like an observable itself might depends on $\mu$.
However, I don't see why it makes sense. For example, scattering amplitude $\mathcal{M}$ is obtained from $Z^{-n/2}\langle \Omega | T... | \Omega \rangle$, as LSZ reduction formula says. Time-ordered product of bare fields would never change as $\mu$ does. Of course, $Z$ factor changes, but change of $\mu$ means that only finite part of $Z$ changes- $Z$ is, however, much bigger because it absorbed divergent part. For these reasons, I guess $\mathcal{M}$ does not depend on $\mu$.
I found.... one possible explanation from Carlo Oleari's lecture note:
(https://virgilio.mib.infn.it/~oleari/public/QCD/appunti_corso/Oleari_QCD-2014-05-04.pdf)

We remark again that $\alpha(s)$ in equation (5.68) comes from the sum of terms to all order in $\alpha(\mu^2)$: this is a crucial point and has many consequences. First of all it implies that all truncated power expansions depend on the renormalization scale $\mu^2$. Only considering contributions to all powers in $\alpha(\mu^2)$ the dependence from $\mu^2$
is lost and the sum of the series is supposed to depend only on s. The previous calculation shows that it happens at the first order in α(s). Since usually one knows only the first terms of a perturbative expansion, the choice of the renormalization scale becomes fundamental.

Probably $\mathcal{M}$ does not depend on $\mu$, but practically any finite-order expansion during the perturbation does. If this is the case, the statement Schwartz's book is quite misleading.
Question

Is $\mathcal{M}$ independent of $\mu$? Is it practically depends on $\mu$ due to finite-order truncation?
Are relationships between observables are independent of $\mu$, even for finite-order truncations? If so, why?

Please give me some clue.

You seem to have already found the answers you're looking for (the perturbation expansions to finite order are scale-dependent, the fully summed "physical" quantities are not); similar points are discussed in this answer of mine. I'm not sure what you want an answer to say here except to affirm that you're right.

@ACuriousMind Right, I'm not sure for this so I need a confirmation... Thank you for your link. I'll go there and read it.

@ACuriousMind btw the second question is still open for me.... if you know the answer, please help me.
